# Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Number JSON.parse

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

Trying to get json data through ajax request, but always get this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Number
```

Here is my js code :

```
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { action : 'getPills' },
        success: function(data){
            product = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(product);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Here is my php code :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_getPills', 'getPills');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getPills', 'getPills');

function getPills(){

        $data = array(
            "test" => 'test'
        );

        error_log(json_encode($data), 0);

        echo json_encode($data);
}
```

called error_log to see what json data I trying to receive:

```
{"test":"test"}
```

I used ajxa+json before on other projects and it was all good. I have no idea how to fix it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution.

I needed to add `die()` at the end of an AJAX handler function to prevent further content. Wordpress was adding `0` at the end of respond. Something like this:

```
{"test":"test"}0
```

So die() at the end of an AJAX handler function fixed the problem

Comment: As it turns out admin-ajax.php always has a 0 in it, visit the url or remove the function process. this answer saved me some frustration thinking that something was wrong. thank you. 

More info here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/admin-ajax-is-returning-0

Comment: 5 years later and you still saved me sooo much time

Answer (score 3):

By specifying `dataType: 'json',` the data passed to the success function will already be deserialized into an object, so you don't call `JSON.parse` on it

```
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
```

Although that should would give you an error like `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` and not `Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected Number`. You should check developer tools to see exactly what is returned by the server.

Comment: thanks for the reply, didn't know that. I removed JSON.parse as you wrote, but still got that error: parsererror 
SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected number"}